# Can not Read or Play a Video in OpenCV+Python using VideoCapture

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video-capture, video-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('traffic.avi')

retval, frame = cap.read()

print retval

================ RESTART: J:\Python For DIP\traffic_video.py ================
False
>>>
```

The Value of retval is always False, which means the video is not read by the command. It must be True to read frames. I don't know what to do. However when I use my default webcam it turns to be True. I tried many videos and the same problem appears. Note: I have installed the ffmpeg correctly.

Note: This is not the full code, in this step I am only validating cap.read() either True or False

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This method is guaranteed 100%

first of all check your version of OpenCV, say for instance 2.4.11. you can check it by typing the following commands in your Python Shell:

```
>>> from cv2 import __version__
>>> __version__
'2.4.11'
>>>
```

Then go to `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin` and copy `opencv_ffmpeg2411.dll`.
Finally go to root directory of Python ex: `C:\Python27` and paste `opencv_ffmpeg2411.dll` in it

> check the name of the file opencv_ffmpeg2411.dll, whether the version
>   of opencv is written or not, if not do the following
>   opencv_ffmpeg(version of your opencv without dots).dll

After that create a new Python file and copy this code and paste it loading your own video

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Capture video from file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('your video')

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)


        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

you will have an output video for example like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIetc.png)

Comment: This worked for me when everything else failed ! (I followed several advises on the net and installed ffmpeg, gstreamer and visual studio libraries, but none of them worked.) Thanks for finally solving my problem.

Comment: What about linux? Is there a similar attempt? None of the other advises i found have worked

Comment: Thank you. and do you have time to answer what WuerfelDev asked?

Comment: @WuerfelDev Unfortunately, I barely use Linux. So I have no idea. Sorry that I couldn't help.

Comment: I tried a lot, but nothing worked for me. In the end I completely wiped Ubuntu 17.04 and installed Ubuntu 17.10. After installing on the new system it is working fine

Comment: It still didn't fix the issue using Python Notebooks. But I switched to PyCharm instead.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the root directory of Python can be a little tricky.  I am using an *Enthought* distribution and, at first, pasted the `opencv_ffmpeg` file into the wrong Python directory.

WRONG:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32
```

RIGHT:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
```

Long story short, make sure you find the right Python directory.